# PST size still large after moving all mails to other PST in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003, pst

I moved ALL the emails from my A.pst to A1.pst and A2.pst.

Originally, my A.pst was about 8 GB, A1.pst became 4 GB, A2.pst became 3 GB but after the move, A.pst is still 3 GB. Why is this Pst not smaller?

Answer (score 2):

You need to Compact it after moving the email. Go to "Data file properties", click the "Advanced button..." and then click "Compact Now".

Answer (score 0):

Right click the PST in outlook and go "Data file properties..." then select "folder size..."

This will give you a break down of where and how much data is stored in your PST